# How to select a particular partition in Postgres when using partition by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query with the following structure -

```
select a.a1,b.b1,c.c1,d.d1,
        count(e.e1) over (partition by e.e2)
from a join b
 on a.aid = b.bid
 join c
 on b.bid = c.cid
 join e
 ......many other joins;
```

The problem is that I want to do something like 
    count(e.e1) over (partition by e.e2 where e.e2 = 'mouse')

I mean I want to partition by the e2 column but consider one of the partitions.

For example, if e2 columns had the following values - "mouse", "cat" and "dog". Then the above query would give an output resembling the following -

```
a11 b11 c11 d11 4  -> record for "mouse" 
a11 b11 c11 d11 5  -> record for "cat"
a11 b11 c11 d11 7  -> record for "dog"
```

Now, I don't want the records for "cat" and "dog". I only want for "mouse".
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data? I don't really understand your question

Comment: Sure. Let me do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when e2 = 'mouse' then 1 else 0 end) over ()
```

This puts the number of "mouse"s on each row in the result set.

EDIT:

If it is based on the column, then you just want:

```
select count(*) over (partition by e2)
```

Comment: Also, even easier is

select sum((e2='mouse')::integer)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see the updated question for more clarification.

Comment: If I do as it says in the edit, then the response would be contain rows for "cat", "dog" and "mouse"